# Changing speed of a point moving along a graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, velocity, marker

I have used the code provided by @Amro in other question:

```
%# control animation speed
DELAY = 0.01;
numPoints = 600;

%# create data
x = linspace(0,10,numPoints);
y = log(x);

%# plot graph
figure('DoubleBuffer','on')                  %# no flickering
plot(x,y, 'LineWidth',2), grid on
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), title('y = log(x)')

%# create moving point + coords text
hLine = line('XData',x(1), 'YData',y(1), 'Color','r', ...
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2);
hTxt = text(x(1), y(1), sprintf('(%.3f,%.3f)',x(1),y(1)), ...
    'Color',[0.2 0.2 0.2], 'FontSize',8, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'VerticalAlignment','top');

%# infinite loop
i = 1;                                       %# index
while true      
    %# update point & text
    set(hLine, 'XData',x(i), 'YData',y(i))   
    set(hTxt, 'Position',[x(i) y(i)], ...
        'String',sprintf('(%.3f,%.3f)',[x(i) y(i)]))        
    drawnow                                  %# force refresh
    %#pause(DELAY)                           %# slow down animation

    i = rem(i+1,numPoints)+1;                %# circular increment
    if ~ishandle(hLine), break; end          %# in case you close the figure
end
```

but I need to change the velocity of the marker. I've tried changing the value of DELAY, but it didn't work. The point is that I can't change the numPoints (size of the function), so I don't know hot to do it.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment the pause(DELAY) in the infinite loop. Change DELAY to a suitable value